# Python redirect C++ library stdout to tempfile while it is also redirected in shell

Tags: python, stdout, io-redirection

I am calling a C++ library in my Python code, and I want to redirect all the stdout of that library into a temp file for post processing. (I know it is a bad design decision.......)

I have read through multiple similar questions and find that this can be done by redirect at the file descriptor level using os.dup2() [Redirect stdout and stderr of an external library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630818/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-of-an-external-library-in-python)

```
redirect_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b')
stdout_fd = sys.stdout.fileno()
sys.stdout.close()
os.dup2(redirect_file.fileno(), stdout_fd)
# call C++ libaray here, capture output in redirect_file
```

However, I find that it only works if the Python script is executed without shell redirection. With shell redirection, the C++ library output will not be captured by temp file, and so I cannot do my post processing.

```
$ python foo.py                        # this works
$ python foo.py > redirected_output     # C++ output will appear in the redirected_output directly
```

Due to other constraint my code must be executed with redirection in shell, so I need to solve it within Python.

Comment: `my code must be executed with redirection in shell` - Please show a sample command showing how you wish to call your Python script.

Comment: python foo.py > redirected_output

Comment: You need to call `fflush` to the library level output. Ref. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/

Comment: Thanks HALF9000. That's exactly what I am missing. It solved my question, thanks!